# Orchard CMS Content Picker Field Placement

Tags: orchardcms

I'm tying to find the Content Picker Placement.Info file, but I cant find it anywhere in the orchard source.  Orchard 1.5

I'm trying to place something like

```
<place Fields_Content_Picker="Content:5" />
```

But this dosent work, Anyone know how to reference the content picker field, or edit field form the placement.info ?

Comment: Ah...  found the Orchard.ContentPicker module it just was on included in the Solution !

Comment: then you should probably close the question.